# Nested Functions, First Class Functions in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, python-3.x

With functions in Python, Js and PHP they all say they are first class objects. I want to make sure I got the PHP example right. Is there any other way of porting this code to PHP?

**Python 3**:

```
def a():
    print("init")
    def b():
        print("inside")
        def c():
            print("inception")
    return c
return b


a()()()
```

*Result*

```
init
inside
inception
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

**Javascript (node)**:

```
function a() {
    console.log("init")
    function b()
    {
        console.log("inside")
        function c()
        {
            console.log("inception")
        }
        return c
    }
    return b
}

s = a()()()
```

*Result*

```
init
inside
inception
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

**PHP 5.5**:

```
function a()
{
    echo "init".PHP_EOL;
    $x = function()
    {
        echo "inside".PHP_EOL;
        $y = function()
        {
            echo "inception".PHP_EOL;
        };
        echo "b".PHP_EOL;
        return $y;
    };
    return $x;
}

a()()();
```

*Result*

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '('
```

**lets try again in PHP**

```
$b = a();
$c = $b();
$c();
```

*Result*

```
init
inside
inception
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Is that the only way to call nested function in PHP?

**UPDATE** Follow up question, in PHP can you return a function the same way as in Python or JS ? or must it be assigned to a variable as a closure first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example will work in PHP 7+. Before that you need to use temporary variables or `call_user_func()` (but that would be quite ugly).

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax

Comment: Can you share the documentation link on the PHP 7+ compatibility?

Comment: Is there a reason I couldn't find this i the Documentation?

Comment: No idea. I found this example in the docs which uses this feature but it doesn't mention that it won't work before 7.0: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-202 Couldn't find anything else (apart from some migration guide).